# How to assign Property of Radio button to a Checkbox

Tags: jquery

I want to assign the property of a Radio button to the checkbox, for example if i change the value of radio button the same should be effected to the checkbox.Below is the code what i have

```
 $(this).children('TD').find('input:radio').change(function()
        {
          $(this).parents('TD').find('input:checkbox').prop(?)
        });
```

Pleases someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `prop` value of `this`:

```
$(this).children('TD').find('input:radio').change(function()
        {
          $(this).parents('TD').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked',this.checked)
        });
```

Note that it won't uncheck the box when you select the radio button off, as it won't call the `change` event on the old button.

Comment: *"Just use the `prop` value of `this`:"* In jQuery 1.6.0 or higher only. In 1.5.x and earlier, it's `attr`. And `$(this).prop('checked')` is a very long-winded way to write `this.checked`. ;-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder As he used `prop` in his question, I would presume he is using  a jQuery version which actually supports it. As for using directly `node.checked`, yes, it certainly is faster, but then you may want to make sure the element actually exists as well, because otherwise you are gonna end up with errors when modifying the DOM element which may or may not exist. If you are willing to traverse the DOM in a matter as he did while being sure that the elements he use actually exist, then why not. EDIT, sorry missed half of your answer, that only applies for the first bit in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you literally mean *value*, as in the `value` attribute, then you can either assign to the element's own `value` property or use jQuery to do it via [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

But I assume you actually mean the *checked state*, not the value, in which case you can either assign directly to the `checked` property of the element, or use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Example:

If you *know* the checkbox will be there, just set its `checked` property directly:

```
$(this).children('TD').find('input:radio').change(function()
    {
      $(this).parents('TD').find('input:checkbox')[0]. checked = this.checked;
      //                             note this ---^^^ We're looking at the raw element
    });
```

Or if you prefer to do it "the jQuery" way or there's any possibility the checkbox won't be there, like this:

```
$(this).children('TD').find('input:radio').change(function()
    {
      $(this).parents('TD').find('input:checkbox').attr("checked", this.checked);
    });
```

Using `attr` to set the checked state works in jQuery 1.5.x and below, and in jQuery 1.6.1 and above; in 1.6.1 or above you could use `prop` instead. For about two weeks (jQuery 1.6.0), you would have *had* to use the new `prop` function, but they rethought that. :-)